# Seeing inside an atom

Tags: experimental-physics, atoms, subatomic

[image: Hydrogen atom]

After seeing this photograph and reading this article : [The First Image Ever of a Hydrogen Atom's Orbital Structure](http://io9.com/the-first-image-ever-of-a-hydrogen-atoms-orbital-struc-509684901)

I was really happy to come to know that orbitals have actually been seen now, but it also made me wonder that how was the orbitals illuminated ? I know that when we send light through a colloidal solution its path is illuminated, but how could the experimental physicists who performed this experiment illuminate an atomic orbital. As I understand it is only a probability density rich region of finding the electron. How is it possible to see/detect a probability density wave ?

Addendum : I understand from the article that the nodal structure is inferred from the interference pattern observed, but how does the interference pattern account for nodal structure, also is this an experimental prove of the results of schrodinger wave equations ?

Addendum 2 : after struggling through this paper http://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.213001
I understood most of the experiment, and got stuck here, I understoot the electrons are ionised and then there interference patterns are observed, but how do the interference pattern represent the shapes of atomic orbitals ? Can the expirement be taken as a solid proof for the establishment of shapes of atomic orbitals ?

Comment: ...the article (to which you linked) describes *exactly* how the atom was imaged.

Answer (score 4):

> How is it possible to see/detect a probability density wave ?

It isn't possible.

The image is a *visualization* of an interference pattern from which the nodal structure of the orbital can be *inferred*.

From a Physics World [article](http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2013/may/23/quantum-microscope-peers-into-the-hydrogen-atom):

> In the new work, Aneta Stodolna, of the FOM Institute for Atomic and
>   Molecular Physics in the Netherlands, along with Marc Vrakking at the
>   Max-Born-Institute in Berlin, Germany, and other colleagues in Europe
>   and the US have shown that photoionization microscopy can directly
>   obtain the nodal structure of the electronic orbital of a hydrogen
>   atom placed in a static electric field. In the experiment, the
>   hydrogen atom is placed in the electric field E and is excited by
>   laser pulses. **The ionized electron escapes from the atom and follows a
>   particular trajectory to the detector** – a dual microchannel plate
>   (MCP) detector – that is perpendicular to the field itself. Given that
>   there are many such trajectories that reach the same point on the
>   detector, **interference patterns can be observed**, which the team
>   magnify by a factor of more than 20,000 using an electrostatic zoom
>   lens. **The interference pattern directly *reflects* the nodal structure
>   of the wavefunction**.

Comment: Ok, but then how does the interference pattern reflect the nodal structure ?

Comment: @rijulgupta, you do understand that the sense of the word "reflects" in the quoted section above is "to make apparent, express or manifest", correct?  They're not using it in the sense of "to throw or bend back light".  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/reflect

Comment: That was humiliating, I do indeed know this much english and it was hurtful because I am just not specialised in this field not stupid in general. Yes, I do know what reflect means here, please do not treat the under specialised crowd as stupid.

Comment: @rijulgupta, you're far too easily humiliated and that's something I have no control over.  Get over it, it was an honest question with no offense intended.

Comment: I am sorry for misinterpreting the comment, I did not know the tone of the comment. Yes ! I know what reflects means here, and I am curious to know how these results were obtained

Comment: @rijulgupta, good.  Then here's the link to their paper:  http://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.110.213001  I'll be driving a long distance the rest of the day so peruse the paper and let me know what you find in it.

Comment: @rijulgupta maybe this can help you as an analogue, how crystal structure is determined http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_crystallography#X-ray_analysis_of_crystals . One uses mathematical transformations to go from the interference patterns on the film to the space locations of the atoms. Something analogous but more complicated here.